# Understanding pivot and layers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

PIVOT:

What's the purpose of the pivot in sprites?

LAYERS:

This is how I currently understand them:

- A newly created 2D project automatically defines the default layer.
- If I add a background image, it will be rendered on the top of the default layer.
- If I add a new layer called background and I set the layer of the background image to newly created layer then the background image will have its own layer.
- If I add a new sprite and I set the layer to be on the background then the sprite will be rendered on the background layer?

Basically layers are like "containers" for sprites or ..what's the purpose on assigning layers to objects/sprites?

Sorting layers:
Basically, a sorting layer is like a container for layers/sprites?

For example : I have three sprites ( mountain,road,water).

If I want to show the mountain and over it add the road and then the water, I should be adding a sorting layer to the mountain and then set the sorting layer of the road/water to the mountain sorting layer?

Comment: pivot is the center of rotation and scale

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - So , if I'm going to rotate the object it will rotate around the pivot? but if the object's pivot is in the left corner for example , the rotation will take place there?

Comment: That is correct. As for sorting layers, assigning these will let you define overlap behavior for groups of objects rather than assigning individual depth numbers every time.